# A have an error "Trying to get property of non-object" in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have code

```
$room = Room::all();
$book = DB::table('book_rooms')
    ->whereDate('check_out', '>=', $request->check_in)
    ->whereDate('check_in', '<=', $request->check_out)
    ->where(function($query) {
        $query->where('status', '=', 0)
            ->orWhere('status', '=', 1);
    })
    ->groupBy('room_id')
    ->get();

return view('admin.Bookroom.list', ['book' => $book, 'room' => $room]);
```

So in file list.blade.php show error 'Trying to get property of non-object'
Please help me! Thank all

Comment: Show us the line on which the error is pointing. Error is produced in view, you are trying to get non-existing property from some variable (i guess from $book)

Comment: line error is "return view('admin.Bookroom.list',['book'=>$book,'room'=>$room]);"
I want passing array book from Controller to file view list but it don't work @Au

Comment: No, error is inside the view.

Answer (score 0):

In your view check does $book not empty and that do with book whatever you want.

```
if($book) {
//your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your query, $book is a collection of records and not just a single record. You can only get the property of a single record. Use an index like `$book[$i].property` to access an individual record's property.